# FragmentManager and androidx FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I'm trying to setup in my app that is using androidX.

My problem is that when I try to work with PlaceAutocompleteFragment I get errors because it is a fragment from `android.app.fragment` and my parent fragment is an androidx fragment: `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` so it uses a `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`instead of a `android.app.FragmentManager`.

How can I work with "old" fragments in androidX?

Comment: The Android self-deprecation society strikes again.

Answer (score 39):

1. Add this to dependencies:
   `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`.
2. Add this: `import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;`.
3. Switch your activity extends from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`.
4. Change from `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

This will fix your issue.

Comment: That introduces this exception at runtime: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120750246

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the new libraries then only use those, don't combine them bacause yo can run into more problems. Now for your problem go to your fragment and just change the import form:

```
import android.app.fragment
```

To:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: This does not solve everything. It appears that getFragmentManager() has not been moved to the androidX class. So there is no real simple replacement for that. Does anybody know how to replace getFragmentManager()?

Comment: OK so activity must extend `FragmentActivity` from `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`, then one can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`;

Comment: That´s rigth, `getFragmentManager()` has been replaced by `getSupportFragmentManagaer()` since the introduction of the support libraries. _Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment and Loader APIs.

When using this class as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the getSupportFragmentManager() and getSupportLoaderManager() methods respectively to access those features._ [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity) @RainerGlüge

Answer (score 4):

There is not any need to get the `FragmentManager` directly from the `Activity` because a replacement method has been provided in the `Fragment` called `getParentFragmentManager`:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

From the docs for the deprecated `getFragmentManager`:

```
 * @deprecated This has been removed in favor of <code>getParentFragmentManager()</code> which
 * throws an {@link IllegalStateException} if the FragmentManager is null. Check if
 * {@link #isAdded()} returns <code>false</code> to determine if the FragmentManager is
 * <code>null</code>.
```

The docs for the replacement method `getParentFragmentManager`:

```
 * Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
 * with this fragment's activity.  Note that this will available slightly
 * before {@link #getActivity()}, during the time from when the fragment is
 * placed in a {@link FragmentTransaction} until it is committed and
 * attached to its activity.
 *
 * <p>If this Fragment is a child of another Fragment, the FragmentManager
 * returned here will be the parent's {@link #getChildFragmentManager()}.
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if not associated with a transaction or host.
```

Just take care to check `isAdded` to make sure that the `FragmentManager` is not null.

Comment: perfectly worked for me i replaced getFragmentManager to getParentFragmentManager  and it worked thanks man

Comment: didn't work for me, it says "Cannot resolve method 'getParentFragmentManager()'"

Comment: It has to be done using: "import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment". [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment). It could happen that the app has not been upgraded to the androidx support libraries?

Comment: Did you try this?
The question below suggests that it won't work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848166/cannot-resolve-method-getparentfragmentmanager