# Cannot resolve method getParentFragmentManager

Tags: android, androidx

I am cleaning a small Android project, and removing the usage of support libraries and the usage of androidx instead seemed promising. Nevertheless, I am facing an strange problem in my MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

private void setupFragments(){
    //...
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getParentFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //...
```

In the old version, `getFragmentManager()` was used instead. Nevertheless, now I get the `Cannot resolve method getParentFragmentManager` compilation error, and get suggested by Android Studio about creating my own getParentFragmentManager function. According to my research, this function should be accessible when importing the androidx libraries, as stated above.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
In case it is related, I am also getting a deprecated warning for FragmentManager from androidx in the definition of my FragmentPagerAdapter:

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { // <---- Deprecated
        super(fm);
    }

Regarding the version of androidx.fragment:fragment being used, I am only using `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2'` as suggested in answers (had nothing before that).

Importing `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction` gave no changes. Also is shown as not being used.

Comment: What version of `androidx.fragment:fragment` are you using?

Comment: Try to import this: import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using : `activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Already tried that, and I get the same error: that function is not found into Activity

Comment: @RomanRdgz you need to extend from FragmentActivity, in order to be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The function has been added in the 1.2.0 version of the Fragment component.

Try changing in your `build.gradle` file (with current stable version): 
    `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2`'

Comment: Did this, refreshed the configuration, rebuilt the code, but the problem persists.

Comment: @RomanRdgz you should use the function inside Fragment class, not Activity

Comment: Ok, therefore how shall I substitute the deprecated getFragmentManager()? That was working while being called from an Activity

Comment: @RomanRdgz As per documentation and the other answers given here: supportFragmentManager

Comment: But I get the very same problem with getSupportFragmentManager: cannot resolve method

Comment: @RomanRdgz make yout activity extend AppCompatActivity, it should resolve your problem

Comment: Wow all this to show a message dialgo on screen. I can do this in one line of code in C#. For Android I have to spend hours on StackOverflow and end up with no answer! Now I have to make a whole activity for a common dialog

Answer (score -1):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager();` instead of using `getParentFramentManager();` and it should work fine.

Comment: Also not found. Had already tried before posting the question