# How to move from an activity to a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to move from an activity named `MyNotes.java` to one fragment named `FragmentNotes.java`. I found that the following codes should be used to perform the movement:

```
Fragment mFragmentNotes = new FragmentNotes ();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_note_id, mFragmentNotes).addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And I think `R.id.fragment_note_id` should be the id of the fragment's layout. (BTW, I am curious why I need to "replace" the id of the fragment's layout when I am simply moving back to the fragment.) However, the above codes do not work, making `mFragmentNotes` with a red line as follows:

[image: fragment]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that a mismatch of fragment types created the problem as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339524/obj-fragment-wrong-2nd-argument-type-found-android-support-v4-app-fragment-re). I solved the problem by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256959/fragmentmanager-and-androidx-fragmentmanager). Hope this helps someone in the same situation that I was in.